# Apache won't start after memcache installation

Tags: apache, memcached

I installed memcache on my Ubuntu 10.04 machine but when it comes to restarting apache it gives me an error. My main root is **/var/www/** and there is only **index.php** file in it.

Everything was working before installing memcache.

[This is what I did.](http://danpaulsmith.com/2011/03/installing-memcache-on-ubuntu-10-04/)

Help please

**ERROR:**

```
myubuntu@ubuntu:~$ service apache2 restart
 * Restarting web server apache2                                                                                                                              (13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

**APACHE LOG:**

```
myubuntu@ubuntu:~$ tail -f  /var/log/apache2/error.log
[Sun Mar 04 14:04:45 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.16 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.3-1ubuntu9.10 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Mar 04 18:54:35 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed Mar 07 20:32:59 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.16 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.3-1ubuntu9.10 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Mar 07 21:01:57 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Mar 09 22:20:06 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.16 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.3-1ubuntu9.10 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Mar 10 01:45:00 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Mar 10 10:58:24 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.16 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.3-1ubuntu9.10 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Mar 10 11:16:49 2012] [error] [client ::1] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Sat Mar 10 11:16:49 2012] [error] [client ::1] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be root. You may want to use **sudo** when starting Apache.

Comment: OMG. It is still morning for me. Solved. Thanks. myubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart